# There's a weird comma before an ampersand in Stack Overflow's title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, grammatical-correction

The title tag reads:

> Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers

I think that the comma before the ampersand should be deleted.

Comment: It is an [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) and is allowed by some style guides.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a [Serial comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma), also known as the Oxford comma. It is used to ensure that the part after `&` is seen as a separate item in the series.

Without the comma, you can interpret the sentence in two different ways:

> - Where Developers
>
>   - Learn
>   - Share
>   - Build Careers

or

> - Where Developers
>
>   - Learn
>   - Share Careers
>   - Build Careers

With the comma only the first interpretation remains.

A popular and funny example:

[image: With the Oxford comma: *We invited the strippers, jfk, and stalin*, illustrated by images of two strippers, and the two historical figures John F. Kennedy and Stalin. Without the Oxford comma: *We invited the strippers, jfk and stalin*, illustrated by two strippers dressed up as the historical figures].

Also see [*Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list) over on English.SE, where you'll find some more examples.

Comment: Well, I just didn't understand the image!

Comment: I tried googling but couldn't find an explanation for it, that image is really good. thank you.

Comment: I'm all for the Oxford comma, but I feel like it looks weird with an ampersand instead of "and".